# Why do police use the word "individual" instead of "person"?

Tags: word-usage

I've noticed that when referring to an unknown perpetrator, police often use the term "individual".

For example see this [article](https://www.wspynews.com/news/wcsjnews/pontiac-police-trying-to-identify-individual-in-fraud-case/article_4cb219e1-4391-5427-859a-795aaf9e724a.html).

What is the purpose of using this word?  I've always found it odd.  "person" seems more natural, and is easier to say.

Are the police trying to emphasize that they are looking for a *single* person instead of potentially *multiple* people?  That's useful information.  But in that case, "person" is also singular, so it would still work.

The word "individual" has a somewhat... clinical feel to it.  Are the police trying to subtly cast the unknown perpetrators as *others*, not worthy of being called "people"?

Comment: I don't think we can give you a good answer as to the reasoning of individual police officers or entire police departments.

Comment: That article wasn't written by "a police department". It was written by a journalist and "individual" was their word choice. Do you have any data that suggests police prefer "individual"? Most press releases from US police departments I've seen tend to use "male/female suspect" or "male/female victim" when they don't know a name.

Comment: Intriguing that that website isn't available to GDPR-compliant countries. What on earth are they doing with personal data?! A relevant quote including the context of who actually used the word would be good here. Links break (either accidentally, or — as here — deliberately).

Comment: My aunt's bag was snatched in the street and the police referred to her in a report of the incident as "an elderly female". She was more annoyed about that than about the bag theft.

Comment: Most industries have ideosyncratic jargon. It arises out of tradition, and it's difficult to give "reasons" why certain phrases happened. In the case of police, I suspect it comes from them trying to sound more educated by using long words.

Comment: @Barmar Except it isn't "police" using the word; it's journalists reporting about police. ( At least based on the one example given)

Comment: @ColleenV I'm assuming they're repeating the language they heard from the police themselves. At least based on what I've seen in TV shows....'

Comment: @Barmar What you've heard on TV shows was also written by not-police. If you want to know what the police say, you should read their press releases. What I see from reading those is that there is no particular bias towards the words  "individual" or "person".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the reason here, but in certain legal contexts, there is a distinction. Legally, [a corporation is a "person,"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_personhood) but it is not an individual; the term "individual" is only applied to humans. Because the word "person" can be ambiguous, it is clearer to say "individual" when specifically referring to a human.

"Individual" cannot refer to corporations, because it refers to something indivisible, and [corporations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakup_of_the_Bell_System) are [divisible](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Oil_Co._of_New_Jersey_v._United_States).

Comment: Such an ambiguity is highly unlikely to arise in reports of typical police activities.

Comment: @jsw29 that's true, but it might be clearer to use "individual" in any legal context so in the (rare) cases where a corporation is involved, confusion can be avoiding without changing the terminology used.

Answer (score 1):

Without putting too fine a point on it, this is an example of *officialese* or *bureaucratese*: the language constraints adopted by governments and other organizations to make their communications more official-sounding. It is the next-of-kin to pomposity.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Officialese):

> Officialese, bureaucratese, or governmentese is language that sounds official. It is the "language of officialdom". Officialese is characterized by a preference for wordy, long sentences; a preference for complex words, code words or buzzwords over simple, traditional ones; a preference for vagueness over directness and a preference for passive over active voice (some of those elements may, however, vary between different times and languages). The history of officialese can be traced to the history of officialdom, as far back as the eldest human civilizations and their surviving official writings.

It is used to impress and intimidate, and sometimes even to confuse or obfuscate. You can't respond if you aren't sure what is being said.

Comment: This is probably the true answer, but it is somewhat too general. *Individual*, the specific word that the question was about, does not seem particularly vague, complex, or confusing, nor does it necessitate the use of long sentences.

Comment: @jsw29: It is simply more formal. To qualify as officialese it would not have to partake of *all* aspects of that class; a single one would do.